# Angular 2 Lazy Loading images

Tags: javascript, angular, lazy-loading

I have problems running the [this](https://github.com/NathanWalker/ng2-image-lazy-load) plugin. I use this [cli](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter). I have add

```
import { ImageLazyLoadModule, WebWorkerService } from "ng2-image-lazy-load";
  imports: [ // import Angular's modules
 ...
    ImageLazyLoadModule,
  ...
    }),
    ...
  ],
```

and (which I am not sure is this the problem)

```
WebWorkerService.workerUrl = '../assets/js/xhrWorker.js';
```

[here](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/blob/master/src/app/app.module.ts). At the html of my Component I have only this:

```
<div imageLazyLoadArea>
    <div>
      <img [imageLazyLoadItem]="img" alt="{{ name }}">
    </div>
</div>
```

where "img" and "name" are @Inputs from parent Component. Does my mistake is way of import of xhrWorker.js file?
(I do have included)

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {HttpModule, Http} from '@angular/http';
```

Comment: You have a custom `xhrWorker.js`file? Why not use the default workerUrl `'assets/js/xhrWorker.js'` (removing `'../'` or remove assignment altogether)? Have you tried that?

Comment: Also, are you sure `alt=".."` is a valid property? What error can you see in your browser console?

Comment: I do not see any errors in console. I have changed to WebWorkerService.workerUrl = 'assets/js/xhrWorker.js'; with no success

Comment: I have created js folder in assets and xhrWorker.js which I have put their code.

Comment: Should I have to add anything in webpack?

Comment: @TeodorKolev have you solved this now? same prob getting now

Comment: @kkpatel I have slove it by stop using this plugin. Now I use https://github.com/tjoskar/ng-lazyload-image

Comment: @TeodorKolev Thanks bro